# How do you use an incremented variable outside of function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

This could be a foolish question; maybe my though process is totally wrong (if so, please point it out), but how do you extract the three incremented variables (c_char, c_word, c_sentence) inside a custom function and use it for other uses?

```
def length_finder(x):
    #variables counting character,word,sentnece  
    c_char = 0
    c_word = 1
    c_sentence = 0

    for i in x:
        if (i >= 'a' and i <= 'z') or (i >= 'A' and i <= 'Z'):
            c_char += 1
        if i == " ":
            c_word += 1
        if i == '.' or i == '!' or i == '?' :
            c_sentence += 1

length_finder(input("Enter the text you wish to analyze: "))

L = 100/c_word*c_char
S = 100/c_word*c_sentence

#formula to get readability
index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8

print("This text is suitable for grade " + str(index))
```

Comment: Return a 3 tuple from the function containing the three variables

Comment: Side note, `(i >= 'A' and i <= 'Z')` can simply be `'A' <= i <= 'Z'`, and then the same for other cases. Also, `i == '.' or i == '!' or i == '?'` can be simply `i in ".!?"`.

Comment: `return c_word, c_char, c_sentence` at the end of the function and then when you call it: `c_word, c_char, c_sentence =length_finder(text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `return` multiple variables from within the function:

```py
def length_finder(x):
    ...
    return (c_char, c_word, c_sentence)


(c_char, c_word, c_sentence) = length_finder('input string')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Make those three variables global, and reference them in the function. You can make them global, then reference them as global within the function.
2. Return them from the function. You can return all 3 values as a dictionary or list.

Comment: Could you kindly give an example of how to make it into a global for this situation? Thanks.

Comment: @DanielJ Don't use globals here for such a simple problem. Globals have a tendency to make code harder to understand and maintain in the long-run. They're an option, but usually a poor one.